# Load onClick() method result in existing WebView

Tags: android, webview

I got following problem.
I created a WebView app. The WebView loads an internet shop. Every link in the shop is opened within the WebView. So far everything works fine.

In the actionbar I got a search Icon. The search Icon opens a new activity "search". In this activity I got a edittext bar and create a search url, to search somethgin in the shop.

Everything works besides, that If i click the search button, the search result is opened in the browser. How can I archive this, that the search result would open in my main activity webview.

Heres some code.

The onClick Method to open the search activity:

```
    public void openSearch(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The code to perform search in the search activity:

```
    public void performSearch(View view){
    String searchURL = "http://interneturl.de/search?page=search&page_action=query&desc=on&sdesc=on&keywords";
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.start_webview);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonSearch);
    if(button.isPressed()){
        //load webView from MainActivity
        webView.loadUrl(searchURL+"="+editText.getText().toString());
        System.out.println("********************************************Button is pressed!!!!");
    }
}
```

The

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.start_webview);
```

is created in the MainActivity

```
public void openMorrisAntikshop() {

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.start_webview); [....]
```

But if i click on the button to search I got a crash.

```
Process: com.csdevelopment2014.morrisantikshop, PID: 16750
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.csdevelopment2014.morrisantikshop.SearchActivity.performSearch(SearchActivity.java:52)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

I appreciate any help, how I could solve this.
Greets

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is that the line `WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.start_webview);` in SearchActivity.class is unable to find the WebView you are referencing. This is because the WebView with the id R.id.start_webview that you used in MainActivity.class is only able to be found if the parent view has been inflated by that activity. So basically, in MainActivity.class, you called `setContentView` and somewhere in that layout you had a WebView with the id R.id.start_webview. This WebView cannot be found via id unless that specific layout has been shown in the Activity. The only way you would be able to reference that WebView from MainActivity.class is if you explicitly referenced the WebView you created in MainActivity.class from SearchActivity.class.

Having explained why your code isn't working, let me show you the correct solution. Instead of trying to reference the WebView created in MainActivity.class, you should be using Intents. These allow Activities to communicate like you are trying to do. What you need to do is to create an explicit Intent that opens up MainActivity.class from SearchActivity.class with the search data, and then load the data in the correct WebView. Here is a simple solution containing the code for both MainActivity.class and SearchActivity.class:

MainActivity.class

```
private WebView mWebView;

public void openMorrisAntikshop() {
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.start_webview);
}

public void loadUrl(String url) {
    if(mWebView != null) {
        // Perform the search
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Handle a new intent coming in, retrieve the URL
    String url = intent.getDataString();
    loadUrl(url);
}
```

SearchActivity.class

```
private static final String SEARCH_URL = "http://interneturl.de/search?page=search&page_action=query&desc=on&sdesc=on&keywords=";

public void performSearch(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonSearch);
    String search = editText.getText().toString();
    if(button.isPressed()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(SEARCH_URL + search), this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Note: You will need to register MainActivity.class in the Android manifest to handle ACTION_VIEW intents for your URL. Put this in the  tag for MainActivity.class:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="interneturl.de" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Hope this helps!